# Entity Framework/dbMigration - Unwanted decimal rounding

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbmigrator

I'm working on a new Code-First Entity Framework (using dbMigration) solution, and I've run into a bit of a snag that I've been unable to get past.

Even though I modified the generated Migration file to set the precision/scale for a decimal field to 18 and 9, when I run the update-database to build the database and call a method I wrote to seed the data, it's rounding the data to 2 decimal places rather than the 9 I expected. In the example data I'm trying to seed, I'm trying to set the Price property to 0.4277 but it's showing up in the database as 0.420000000

I've been looking all over for solutions to this problem, including creating an override (in my context class) for OnModelCreating, to force the precision/scale there. But when I have that in place (see the commented out line in the code below), while the database migration still works exactly as planned (including creating a DECIMAL(18,9) as expected), now the Seed call doesn't run.

I'm hoping I'm just missing something small (and easy to fix). But can anyone offer suggestions what I can try?

Below is the relevant code (including the initially-generated migration code):

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ConfiguratorContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ConfiguratorContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
        SeedData.Initialize();        
    }
}

public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Products",
            c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Price = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 9)
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);
    }   

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Products");
    }       
}   

public class ConfiguratorContext : DbContext
{
    public ConfiguratorContext() : base("name=ConfiguratorConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ConfiguratorContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ConfiguratorContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(a => a.Price).HasPrecision(18, 9);
    }
}

public class SeedData
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        using (var context = new ConfiguratorContext())
        {
            if (context.Products.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }

            context.Products.Add(new Product
            {
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(0.4277),
            });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your seed is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`. It should only run once, until you actually drop the database.

Comment: Yes, for testing purposes I've been manually dropping the database (for now) to test it, and when I do so, it's still truncating the (18,9) decimal to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your migration is not executing and database is created with `decimal(18, 2)` by default.

You can try to use the following initializer, but it does not created database for your

```
Database.SetInitializer<ConfiguratorContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ConfiguratorContext, Configuration>());
```

The line you have commented `modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(a => a.Price).HasPrecision(18, 9);` does the job just right.

I would advice to move away from automatic migrations if you can, and update databases through `Update-Database` to have consistent and predictable results on database schema changes.

Comment: It would appear the automatic migration was the problem - once I turned that off, it all worked like magic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- First of all leave the body of the OnModelCreating method uncommented. That will ensure the precision of the Price column in the DB.
- In the seed method set the value like this:
  `Price = 0.4277m` instad of  `Price = Convert.ToDecimal(0.4277),`

Comment: Yes, that's why I had that line there in the first place - the thing is, with that line uncommented, for some reason my Seed method never fires. The database is created as expected, but there is no data.

Also, I already tried the Price = 0.4277m instead of the Convert.ToDecimal as well, with no different results.